# Does the GDB debugger work in Code::Blocks 16.01 when run from a Windows VM via Parallels?

Tags: debugging, gdb, codeblocks, parallels

I've looked through the common reasons that the debugger might not work in C::B, but I haven't been able to find anything online that addresses my particular question.

When I try to start debugging, the debugger spits out the log below.

Has anyone been able to get the gdb debugger to work in C::B when running Parallels?

```
Starting debugger: C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe -nx -fullname -quiet  -args /Mac/Home/Desktop/Foo/bin/Debug/Foo.exe
done

[debug]> set prompt >>>>>>cb_gdb:

Registered new type: wxString
Registered new type: STL String
Registered new type: STL Vector
Setting breakpoints

[debug]/Mac/Home/Desktop/Foo/bin/Debug/Foo.exe: No such file or directory.
[debug](gdb) >>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> show version
[debug]GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
[debug]Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[debug]License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
[debug]This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
[debug]There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
[debug]and "show warranty" for details.
[debug]This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
[debug]For bug reporting instructions, please see:
[debug]<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set confirm off

Debugger name and version: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1

[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set width 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set height 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set breakpoint pending on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print asm-demangle on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set unwindonsignal on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set print elements 0
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set new-console on
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> set disassembly-flavor att
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> source C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\share\codeblocks/scripts/stl-views-1.0.3.gdb
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> directory /Mac/Home/Desktop/Foo/
[debug]Source directories searched: /Mac/Home/Desktop/Foo;$cdir;$cwd
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> break "//Mac/Home/Desktop/Foo/main.c:12"
[debug]No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
[debug]Breakpoint 1 ("//Mac/Home/Desktop/Foo/main.c:12") pending.
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:
[debug]> run
[debug]No executable specified, use `target exec'.
[debug]Starting program:  
[debug]>>>>>>cb_gdb:

Starting the debuggee failed: No executable specified, use `target exec'.

[debug]> quit

Debugger finished with status 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that gdb can't handle a path that descends from the root directory on OS X, even if it appears that you've removed all spaces from the path (which is the typical solution on Windows if you look around the web).

Although far from ideal, to be able to debug a project in Code::Blocks on a Windows VM, you need to create the project in a folder that descends from the virtual C:\ directory. Then the debugger should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem that I solved my right clicking on my .cpp files, going to properties, then the build tab and making sure that the "Compile file" and the "Link file" boxes are checked and the "Belongs in targets:" "Debug" and "Release" boxes are checked.